# Calling a blocking DLL function from a goroutine?

Tags: go, dll

I'm writing a Go program for Windows that will call into a C DLL that I wrote and built separately.  The C function will run an event loop that spends spend most of its time in a blocking system call.

The goroutine looks like this:
1) Load the DLL
2) Find the function by name
3) call it, which will return only when I'm shutting down the process.

I know goroutines aren't "real" threads but is it safe to treat it as one in this case?  So far this program seems to do exactly what I want it to but I'm a little worried the goroutine scheduler is going to bite me at some point.

Is this safe?  Thanks!

Comment: It is safe. https://www.quora.com/Go-programming-language-What-happens-when-a-goroutine-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Then you make syscall all os thread locks and waits the syscall end. All other threads works well.

For better concurrency you can use [runtime.LockOSThread()](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) to move out all goroutines from current os thread.